# How to set the remote notification sound for iOS in react native app?

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Im using react-native-firebase and firebase cloud messaging for remote notifications (v5.6.0), and I have my firebase cloud function's notification payload set. Im trying to set the notification sound for iOS/android. what I have currently is:

```
exports.sendChatNotification = functions.firestore.document('messages/{document}').onCreate((event) => {
    const writeData = event.data();

    const { receiverToken, senderName, content } = writeData;

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Chat Message',
            body: senderName + ' has sent you a message',
            sound: 'Complete'
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiverToken, payload).then((msgDevicesResponse) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msgDevicesResponse));
    });
});
```

Currently experiencing this notification sound playing the default for iOS, and am unable to per-select an existing iOS tone, such as "Complete". I understand from reading firebase docs that the 'sound' property of the notification payload only works for the android platform.

Since im using react-native-firebase, I looked at their documentation for Cloud Messaging, and found this Notification object that has `iOS` and `android` properties: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging/notification

both platform properties have a sub-property `sound`, but Im unsure of how to integrate this, considering my notifications are being set in a firebase cloud function, which uses `firebase.admin`

My goal is to set the iOS notification sound from the os's list of tones. How can this be done?